# How to iterate and assign value to a column in a dataframe using apply lambda method using a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, dataframe

I want to assign value to a column in dataframe by writing a function with my desired set of conditions and then apply it to the column in dataframe column using apply lambda method.

The dataset and expected output snippet

```
 index Close_x buynifty square_buynifty nbuy
   0     5000    0             0          0
   1     5100    0             0          0
   2     5300    1             0         5300
   3     5101    0             0         5300
   4     5009    1             0         5300
   5     5201    0             1         5201
   6     5400    0             0          0
   7     5500    0             1          0
   8     5450    0             0          0
   9     5388    1             0         5388
   10    5402    0             0         5388
   11    5499    0             0         5388
   12    5610    0             1         5610
   13    5701    0             0          0
   14    5648    0             0          0
```

I have tried creating the function and assigning the value using a `lambda` expression, but the value is not getting assigned and nor is it throwing any error.

```py
dd['nbuy']=0

def tst(nbuy,buynifty,square_buynifty,Close_x,df):

    df=[]
    for i in range(0,len(df)):

        if buynifty[i]==1 and nbuy[i]==0:
            nbuy[i]=Close_x[i]

        elif (square_buynifty[i]==0):
            nbuy[i+1]=nbuy[i]
        elif (square_buynifty[i]==1 and nbuy[i-1]>0):
            nbuy[i]=Close_x[i]
            nbuy[i+1]=0
        elif (square_buynifty[i]==1 and nbuy[i-1]==0):
            nbuy[i]=0
            nbuy[i+1]=0
    return nbuy
dd['nbuy']= dd.apply(lambda row: tst(row['nbuy'],row['buynifty'],row['square_buynifty'],row['Close_x'],dd), axis=1)
```

I want to assign values row wise through the function defined `'tst'` to `'nbuy'` column of my existing dataframe `'dd'`. `'buynifty'` , `square_buynifty'` are already existing columns and are binary variables. `'Close_x'` is a float value similar to closing price of a stock

The output I get in `nbuy` column is only zeros at each row which is the same as it was initialised. `nbuy` should take values of `close_x` or 0 depending on the function calculations but it is throwing just zeroes. Kindly help me solve this issue.

Comment: Could you supply some sample start data and what the output of that sample data would look like?

Comment: Please see the image for sample of dataset and desired output

Comment: It seems you are trying to build data row by row - that's not he intended use for DataFrame to the best of my understanding. Try reading the unprocessed data from somewhere (DB, csv file, numpy ndarray, etc...) and then consider pandas' `applymap` and `shift` methods to achieve what you described

Comment: @JD_Trader please supply `code-formatted` data rather than an image so that we may copy it directly.

Comment: There are several issues with your code that wont work: (1) the df=[ ] before the for loop overrides the value of the df variable. (2) It looks like the loop is overriding the values set in previous iterations (by modifying i+1, i-1). (3) The apply is meant to be used looking at each row/column of the dataframe independently, the current use defeats the purpose, I'd recommend either looping on the dataframe of constructing the rules with no loop and no apply.
It looks like the rules are simple enough to code without a loop, but you would need to be more explicit about what the conditions are.

Comment: The data above already has an `nbuy` column. Is this supposed to be there?

Comment: `df = []; for i in range(len(df)): ...`: you will never enter the loop because you empty df just before...

Comment: After shifting the empty df inside the loop, ("'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'", u'occurred at index 0') errors pops up.